# Audio is not working but video does on WebRTC

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc

I'm setting my video-conference service for academic purposes using WebRTC and everything works fine except for the audio capture. When I go to my website, it will only ask permission for the video camera, but not for the audio, and of course it just won't be any audio...

My main.js

```
'use strict';

var isChannelReady = false;
var isInitiator = false;
var isStarted = false;
var localStream;
var pc;
var remoteStream;
var turnReady;

var pcConfig = {
    'iceServers': [{
        'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
    }]
};

// Set up audio and video regardless of what devices are present.
var sdpConstraints = {
    offerToReceiveAudio: true,
    offerToReceiveVideo: true
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////

var room = 'foo';
// Could prompt for room name:
// room = prompt('Enter room name:');

var socket = io.connect();

if (room !== '') {
    socket.emit('create or join', room);
    console.log('Attempted to create or  join room', room);
}

socket.on('created', function(room) {
    console.log('Created room ' + room);
    isInitiator = true;
});

socket.on('full', function(room) {
    console.log('Room ' + room + ' is full');
});

socket.on('join', function (room){
    console.log('Another peer made a request to join room ' + room);
    console.log('This peer is the initiator of room ' + room + '!');
    isChannelReady = true;
});

socket.on('joined', function(room) {
    console.log('joined: ' + room);
    isChannelReady = true;
});

socket.on('log', function(array) {
    console.log.apply(console, array);
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////

function sendMessage(message) {
    console.log('Client sending message: ', message);
    socket.emit('message', message);
}

// This client receives a message
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('Client received message:', message);
    if (message === 'got user media') {
        maybeStart();
    } else if (message.type === 'offer') {
        if (!isInitiator && !isStarted) {
            maybeStart();
        }
        pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
        doAnswer();
    } else if (message.type === 'answer' && isStarted) {
        pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
    } else if (message.type === 'candidate' && isStarted) {
        var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
            sdpMLineIndex: message.label,
            candidate: message.candidate
        });
        pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    } else if (message === 'bye' && isStarted) {
        handleRemoteHangup();
    }
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var localVideo = document.querySelector('#localVideo');
var remoteVideo = document.querySelector('#remoteVideo');

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true
})
    .then(gotStream)
    .catch(function(e) {
        alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name);
    });

function gotStream(stream) {
    console.log('Adding local stream.');
    localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    localStream = stream;
    sendMessage('got user media');
    if (isInitiator) {
        maybeStart();
    }
}

var constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: true
};

console.log('Getting user media with constraints', constraints);

if (location.hostname !== 'localhost') {
    requestTurn(
        'https://computeengineondemand.appspot.com/turn?username=41784574&key=4080218913'
    );
}

function maybeStart() {
    console.log('>>>>>>> maybeStart() ', isStarted, localStream, isChannelReady);
    if (!isStarted && typeof localStream !== 'undefined' && isChannelReady) {
        console.log('>>>>>> creating peer connection');
        createPeerConnection();
        pc.addStream(localStream);
        isStarted = true;
        console.log('isInitiator', isInitiator);
        if (isInitiator) {
            doCall();
        }
    }
}

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    sendMessage('bye');
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function createPeerConnection() {
    try {
        pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
        pc.onicecandidate = handleIceCandidate;
        pc.onaddstream = handleRemoteStreamAdded;
        pc.onremovestream = handleRemoteStreamRemoved;
        console.log('Created RTCPeerConnnection');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: ' + e.message);
        alert('Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object.');
        return;
    }
}

function handleIceCandidate(event) {
    console.log('icecandidate event: ', event);
    if (event.candidate) {
        sendMessage({
            type: 'candidate',
            label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
            id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
            candidate: event.candidate.candidate
        });
    } else {
        console.log('End of candidates.');
    }
}

function handleRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
    console.log('Remote stream added.');
    remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
    remoteStream = event.stream;
}

function handleCreateOfferError(event) {
    console.log('createOffer() error: ', event);
}

function doCall() {
    console.log('Sending offer to peer');
    pc.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, handleCreateOfferError);
}

function doAnswer() {
    console.log('Sending answer to peer.');
    pc.createAnswer().then(
        setLocalAndSendMessage,
        onCreateSessionDescriptionError
    );
}

function setLocalAndSendMessage(sessionDescription) {
    // Set Opus as the preferred codec in SDP if Opus is present.
    //  sessionDescription.sdp = preferOpus(sessionDescription.sdp);
    pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
    console.log('setLocalAndSendMessage sending message', sessionDescription);
    sendMessage(sessionDescription);
}

function onCreateSessionDescriptionError(error) {
    trace('Failed to create session description: ' + error.toString());
}

function requestTurn(turnURL) {
    var turnExists = false;
    for (var i in pcConfig.iceServers) {
        if (pcConfig.iceServers[i].url.substr(0, 5) === 'turn:') {
            turnExists = true;
            turnReady = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!turnExists) {
        console.log('Getting TURN server from ', turnURL);
        // No TURN server. Get one from computeengineondemand.appspot.com:
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                var turnServer = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                console.log('Got TURN server: ', turnServer);
                pcConfig.iceServers.push({
                    'url': 'turn:' + turnServer.username + '@' + turnServer.turn,
                    'credential': turnServer.password
                });
                turnReady = true;
            }
        };
        xhr.open('GET', turnURL, true);
        xhr.send();
    }
}

function handleRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
    console.log('Remote stream added.');
    remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
    remoteStream = event.stream;
}

function handleRemoteStreamRemoved(event) {
    console.log('Remote stream removed. Event: ', event);
}

function hangup() {
    console.log('Hanging up.');
    stop();
    sendMessage('bye');
}

function handleRemoteHangup() {
    console.log('Session terminated.');
    stop();
    isInitiator = false;
}

function stop() {
    isStarted = false;
    // isAudioMuted = false;
    // isVideoMuted = false;
    pc.close();
    pc = null;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////

// Set Opus as the default audio codec if it's present.
function preferOpus(sdp) {
    var sdpLines = sdp.split('\r\n');
    var mLineIndex;
    // Search for m line.
    for (var i = 0; i < sdpLines.length; i++) {
        if (sdpLines[i].search('m=audio') !== -1) {
            mLineIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (mLineIndex === null) {
        return sdp;
    }

    // If Opus is available, set it as the default in m line.
    for (i = 0; i < sdpLines.length; i++) {
        if (sdpLines[i].search('opus/48000') !== -1) {
            var opusPayload = extractSdp(sdpLines[i], /:(\d+) opus\/48000/i);
            if (opusPayload) {
                sdpLines[mLineIndex] = setDefaultCodec(sdpLines[mLineIndex],
                    opusPayload);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    // Remove CN in m line and sdp.
    sdpLines = removeCN(sdpLines, mLineIndex);

    sdp = sdpLines.join('\r\n');
    return sdp;
}

function extractSdp(sdpLine, pattern) {
    var result = sdpLine.match(pattern);
    return result && result.length === 2 ? result[1] : null;
}

// Set the selected codec to the first in m line.
function setDefaultCodec(mLine, payload) {
    var elements = mLine.split(' ');
    var newLine = [];
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (index === 3) { // Format of media starts from the fourth.
            newLine[index++] = payload; // Put target payload to the first.
        }
        if (elements[i] !== payload) {
            newLine[index++] = elements[i];
        }
    }
    return newLine.join(' ');
}

// Strip CN from sdp before CN constraints is ready.
function removeCN(sdpLines, mLineIndex) {
    var mLineElements = sdpLines[mLineIndex].split(' ');
    // Scan from end for the convenience of removing an item.
    for (var i = sdpLines.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var payload = extractSdp(sdpLines[i], /a=rtpmap:(\d+) CN\/\d+/i);
        if (payload) {
            var cnPos = mLineElements.indexOf(payload);
            if (cnPos !== -1) {
                // Remove CN payload from m line.
                mLineElements.splice(cnPos, 1);
            }
            // Remove CN line in sdp
            sdpLines.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }

    sdpLines[mLineIndex] = mLineElements.join(' ');
    return sdpLines;
}
```

and my index.js (server)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var cors = require('cors');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('host.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('host.cert', 'utf8');
var os = require('os');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    //console.log('Servidor en marxa.');
});

console.log('Servidor ON');

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials,app);

httpServer.listen(80,"0.0.0.0");
httpsServer.listen(443,"0.0.0.0");
var io = require("socket.io");
io = io.listen(httpServer);
io = io.listen(httpsServer);

//EL SERVER ESTA CONFIGURAT I FUNCIONA//

var usersConnected = [];
var nUsersConnected = 0;

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    function log() {
        var array = ['Message from server:'];
        array.push.apply(array, arguments);
        socket.emit('log', array);
    }

    usersConnected.push(socket.id);
    nUsersConnected++;

    log('Welcome to WebRTC Server: Miguel & Pavel');
    console.log('New user connected: '+socket.id+' #Users connected = '+nUsersConnected);

    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        log('Client said: ', message);
        // for a real app, would be room-only (not broadcast)
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
    });

    socket.on('create or join', function(room) {
        log('Received request to create or join room ' + room);

        var numClients = io.sockets.sockets.length;
        log('Room ' + room + ' now has ' + numClients + ' client(s)');

        if (numClients === 1) {
            socket.join(room);
            log('Client ID ' + socket.id + ' created room ' + room);
            socket.emit('created', room, socket.id);

        } else if (numClients === 2) {
            log('Client ID ' + socket.id + ' joined room ' + room);
            io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
            socket.join(room);
            socket.emit('joined', room, socket.id);
            io.sockets.in(room).emit('ready');
        } else { // max two clients
            socket.emit('full', room);
        }
    });

    socket.on('ipaddr', function() {
        var ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
        for (var dev in ifaces) {
            ifaces[dev].forEach(function(details) {
                if (details.family === 'IPv4' && details.address !== '127.0.0.1') {
                    socket.emit('ipaddr', details.address);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function (message) {
        nUsersConnected--;
        console.log('User: '+socket.id+' disconnected #Users connected = '+nUsersConnected);
        /*if(usuari1 == socket.id){
         io.to(usuari2).emit('message', {type:'hangup'});
         }else{
         io.to(usuari1).emit('message', {type:'hangup'});
         }*/


        //tots els usuaris s'han desconnectat
        if(nUsersConnected == 0){
            console.log('All users have been deleted');
            nUsersConnected = 0;
            usersConnected = [];
        }
    })
    socket.on('bye', function(){
        console.log('received bye');
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: you didn't post any console.log message. Read your console.log message it should throw some error

Answer (score 2):

> When I go to my website, it will only ask permission for the video camera, but not for the audio, and of course it just won't be any audio

Am suspecting issue with your system microphone.
If your microphone is proper, then your localstream should have audioTracks `localStream.getAudioTracks()`. And if we unmute localVideo element, it should echo the audio.

Try this demo https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/ to test your microphone. Update your question with the results.

Google stopped providing turn servers with below url, so you need to setup your TurnServer. Try [CoTURN](https://github.com/coturn/coturn).

```
requestTurn(
    'https://computeengineondemand.appspot.com/turn?username=41784574&key=4080218913'
);
```